# Wordpress, Woocommerce site some of products images not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone help, why my website products images not showing, even when i try to see them in media folder its show blank space, But All images are still exists in upload folder. When i inspect and find the image url and open it, It shows the page not found. 
For you reference Please check the website: [enter link description here](https://www.my1004mart.com/shop/)

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I think your thumbnail files exist (even though WordPress shows `page not found`), I mean, I tried visiting [a non-existing-file](https://www.my1004mart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Not-existing-file.jpg) link and `Apache` shows `404` error (and I do not know which version of `WordPress` your site is using) but in my experience `Apache` never shows **`404`** error directly and transfers the request to `WordPress` which then shows "`page not found`" (maybe your `.htaccess` file has some issues too).

1. Ensure your `uploads` directory and files have correct permissions (see [related post](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/) about how to do that).
2. Ensure your `.htaccess` file redirects correctly to `WordPress` (try visiting [a non-existing-file](https://www.my1004mart.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Not-existing-file.jpg) link by your self, until fixed).
3. If security is an issue you should not disclose further information here (else open another question with more details).

Example `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I check various file that are not showing on front page or shop page it exists in upload folder.

Comment: Further More i tried to regenerate the thumbnail as well

Comment: Updated! (but may still not work, in which case you probably should take direct help from an advanced `WordPress` developer).